# Store data from .json to eth smart contract/solidity

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, json-rpc

is it possible to store data from .json file to blockchain via smart contract and if yes, how?
I mean i have a json file with 4 total variables or a struct inside a struct, which i want to read, store and view via a smart contract.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few people have put json parsers on chain, but it's generally an expensive task.  The best idea is to usually just parse them off-chain and input them manually as to what you want them to be.